# Error:The filename try.xlsx is not readable in excel_reader2.php

Tags: php

I want to read the Uploaded Excel file in php. so i downloaded excel_reader2.php

from following link

[link](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list)

when I inserted this into my code i got following Error:

```
The filename try.xlsx is not readable.
```

My code is:

```
if (file_exists($filepath))
{
    echo "File present";
}

else
{
die('The file ' . $filename . ' was not found');
}

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($filename,false);

$data->read($filename);

$data->val(1, 'A');

echo $data;
```

So after searching in Google I got link that is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983298/the-filename-feed1-xls-is-not-readable-in-php)

After Following this also i am getting same error.

So can any one help me, where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using PHPExcel at all? Or simply tagging it as PHPExcel because you believe that PEAR SEW is the same as PHPExcel?

Comment: do you got solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PEAR SEW cannot read OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) format files, only the older BIFF (.xls) format files. If you want to read .xlsx files, then you need a reader library that does support that format such as [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)