# The filename propertyIk.xls is not readable is given when trying to read from Excel files

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Im trying to read from excel files using php excel.. i can read from some files.but cant read from some files too. 'The filename propertyIk.xls is not readable' error is given.

both the files have same permissions(0666)

can someone help me here? 
suggest me how to fix this or suggest me new way please

thank you guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983298/the-filename-feed1-xls-is-not-readable-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141568/errorthe-filename-try-xlsx-is-not-readable-in-excel-reader2-php

Comment: http://wildesign.ca/php-excel-reader-and-the-dreaded-file-not-readable-error/

Comment: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10373306-RESOLVED-Excel-reader-for-PHP